# Hightlight text on multiple line

Tags: jquery, regex, annotations, highlight

I try to use jquery to highlight text.

I have follow this fiddle solution : http://jsfiddle.net/thelinh/UPs3V/

[image]

It's work to search and highlight text that don't contain line break tags (`<br/>`) tags.

But in case text contain `<br/>` tags. the solution doesn't work.

Please help me.

Thanks.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/UPs3V/80/

[image]

Comment: Please use inline code within markup instead of pointing to external websites Thelinh. Try to make the question self-contained, and use the images and outside links only for clarification.

Comment: And of course the obligatory remark: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/589259

Answer (score 0):

try replacing your term with

```
var term = "high(?:<br\s*/?>)?lighting";
```